# Запуск скомпилированного файла в ubuntu

Tags: c++, c, gcc, кросс-компиляция

Всем привет , интересуюсь c++ , вот появился вопрос , скомпилировал я код,
появляется у меня скомпилированный файл который надо запустить , но он в формате exe , wine у меня не установлен , можно ли сделать чтобы компилятор создал программу не в .exe формате а в том формате , который я бы смог открыть через ubuntu ?

Либо сделать универсальный формат , если есть такой .

Comment: 1 Что мешает вам скомпилировать код в gcc под Убунтой для нативной платформы?
2 Что мешает вам в Убунте установить и настроить wine?

Comment: Я в курсе про Wine , меня интересует можно ли задать правило компилятору , чтобы он создал бинарник не в .exe формате , а в том на который нажав мышкой 2 раза , он откроется как и с .exe на винде

Comment: Если вы под Убунтой в gcc компилируете exe-файл, то есть исполняемый файл для платформы win-32, если я вас правильно понял, тогда сами понимаете, что это возможно, так как gcc по умолчанию, компилирует под нативную платформу (x86_64).
Только, как вам написали в ответе, не всякий код написанный под одну платформу, без учёта кросс-компиляции, возможно сходу собрать под другой.

Comment: g++ -o hello main.cpp , он не компилирует под ubuntu , такойже обычный .exe файл

Comment: я вас понял , но вопрос был в том что , как через gcc скомпилировать исполняемый файл для ubuntu так , чтобы он открылся при нажатии на него 2йным щелчком ( также как .exe в винде)

Comment: Вопрос изначально глупый. В любом DE, любой unix-подобной ОС любой исполняемый файл, при наличии бита исполнимости, запускается при двойном клике мышкой.
gcc, по умолчанию, устанавливает бит наполняемости, на выходные исполняемые файлы. Тем не менее, я вам дал ответ, но от вас последовали ещё более глупые вопросы, говорящие о том, что вы вообще и близко не знакомы не то что с программированием, а даже элементарным устройством ОС.

Answer (score 4):

**Кривой путь**: гуглить про кросс-компиляцию. Например, если Cygwin, то (примерно, давно такой ерундой не занимался):

1. Качаем последнюю версию [crosstool-ng](http://crosstool-ng.org/download/crosstool-ng/)
2. Распаковываем её куда-нибудь в cygwin shell, запускаем `./configure` (доустанавливаем то, на что она матерится - bison, flex, cvs, wget, исходники/библиотеку ncurses, и т.д.)
3. `make`, `make install`, и дальше - по инструкциям [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4769968/).

**Неожиданный путь**: поставить [Open Watcom](ftp://ftp.openwatcom.org/pub) для Windows (при установке не забыть поставить галочку у Linux в target platform). Создание нового проекта в нём:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Может прокатить :) Хотя поддержки последних стандартов от него ждать не приходится, но "Hello, world" исправно собирает :)

**Правильный путь**: поставить убунту в виртуалке и собирать в ней.

И в любом случае готовиться к тому, что исходники, без проблем собирающиеся под Windows, придётся дорабатывать напильником. После чего может возникнуть желание пойти по совсем правильному пути: работать под Linux, а Windows держать в виртуалке :)

> Либо сделать универсальный формат , если есть такой .

Perl, Python, Ruby...

Comment: скорее поставлю windows на виртуалку как вы и сказали , нежели с ubuntu переходить заново на windows и ставить ubuntu на виртуалку windows ))

Answer (score 0):

/tmp/test.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello, world!" << std::endl;
    return 0; 
}
```

`cd && /tmp && c++ test.cpp -o test && ./test`

При клике мышкой на консольный файл, как в винде, Убунта терминал не откроет, по этому нужно или запустить исполняемый файл из терминала или создать ярлык на терминал, с параметром `-e` вашего исполняемого файла.

Больше информации в `man gcc`

Comment: А если завтра мне понадобятся программы с графической оболочкой , которые можно запустить двойным кликом в убунту , мне что придется их черезе терминал исполнять? 
Или ссылку давать постоянно